# Locking on to enemy, player can only move towards enemy, not away?

Tags: unity, c#, character

I'm working on a lock on function and so far I can lock on to the nearest enemy, but my player can't move around the enemy, i can only move towards it. I have my project setup so that the camera is always at a fixed position/rotation, and the player moves independently of the camera.

Here's my move function:

```
public void Move(float h, float v) {
    if (!lockPlayerMovement) {
        Speed = 0;
        MoveDirection.y -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Mathf.Abs(v) > ThumbStickDeadZone || (Mathf.Abs(h) > ThumbStickDeadZone)) {
            var lookRotation = new Vector3();
            lookRotation.Set(h, 0, v);
            lookRotation = lookRotation.normalized;

            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookRotation, Vector3.up);
            if (lookRotation.magnitude > ThumbStickDeadZone) {
                Speed = RunSpeed;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * TurnSpeed);
            }
        }
        if (Controller.isGrounded) {
            MoveDirection = Transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward).normalized;
            MoveDirection *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
            //if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            //      MovementProperties.MoveDirection.y = JumpSpeed;
        }
        Controller.Move(MoveDirection);
    }
}
```

Lock On Function:

```
void Update () {
    playerPosition = transform;

    if (enemyLockedOn && enemyTarget != null) {
        transform.LookAt(enemyTarget.transform);
    }
}



void ScanForEnemies() {
    int numOfEnemies = 0;

    float distanceFromPlayer;
    GameObject closestEnemy;

    List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();

    Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

    foreach (Collider col in cols) {
        if (col && col.tag == "Enemy") {
            ++numOfEnemies;
            enemies.Add(col.gameObject);
            //print(Vector3.Distance(playerPosition.position, col.transform.position));
        }
    }

    if (enemies.Count > 0) {
        distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(playerPosition.position, enemies[0].transform.position);
        closestEnemy = enemies[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++) {
            if (Vector3.Distance(playerPosition.position, enemies[i].transform.position) < distanceFromPlayer) {
                distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(playerPosition.position, enemies[i].transform.position);
                closestEnemy = enemies[i];
            }
        }

        /* Set closest enemy as the player target and lock player to that enemy (while in range -- or scan pressed again) */
        enemyTarget = closestEnemy;

        if (enemyTarget != null) enemyLockedOn = true;

        print("Closest Enemy : " + closestEnemy + " | Distance From Player : " + distanceFromPlayer);
        print("Number of nearest enemies : " + numOfEnemies);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite some code there, and some variables which are not explained, but I think the culprit is:

```
MoveDirection = Transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward).normalized;
```

This line makes the `MoveDirection` variable to move towards the +Z axis. Assuming that the code that handles this movement is changing the player's `localPosition`, this means that the player will be moving towards the direction it is pointing, in this case the locked enemy.

To move backwards, you can either use `-Vector3.forward` or `Vector3.back`, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to implement that in your project, as I can only see part of it.

Or the alternative is this line:

```
MoveDirection *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

If you set `speed` to a negative values (as in, going backwards) this line will automatically make the player move backwards.